# Creating a jump delay if you fall too far

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a delay before the player can jump again if they fall from a height greater than for example 5.0f. Currently, there's no delay no matter what, which should not be the case.

```
// Player jumping
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded && Time.time > canJump)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
            if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out var hit)) return;

            if (hit.distance > 5.0f)
            {
                canJump = Time.time + 1.0f; // Delay next jump
            }
        }
```

I have an empty game object called 'groundCheck' that sits directly below my player with a layer mask attached called 'Ground' which I use for my regular jumping and movement and all my terrain/objects have the 'Ground' layer. I tried to create an if statement so that if my player fell from at least 5.0f, they would have a very brief jump delay, but that didn't work and I'm now having issues with my raycast.

Comment: This checks if the distance to the ground at the moment you jump is more than 5. It will always be 0 though since you can only jump while on the ground

Comment: Your comment actually helped give me more information that I wasn't thinking about. I used that to take out the raycast from my jump if statement and put it on its own and it now works as it should. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you've solved your problem, but allow me to still suggest that instead of raycasting, you can store the position where the player was last grounded. When the player lands, check if the Y difference between their last grounded position and the new one is less than -5.

Comment: Yeah I will try that aswell. The raycast is good so far however if for example you are jumping from platform to platform at a great height, you can't jump because the raycast is going straight to the ground. I will try to figure out your solution also

Comment: Alternatively, you can check for the vertical velocity value of your player's Rigidbody on collision with the ground. if(rigidbody.velocity.y > _fallDamageValue) { canJump = Time.time + 1.0f; // Delay next jump }

Comment: I'm actually using a character controller for my character